# ivh-TreeView AngularJs Get Node id On Label Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, treeview

Im new to AngularJs and I have used Angular Ivh_treeview component for displaying a nested tree from JSON data. The Tree is loaded correctly. Now i want to

Get the Node Id On Label Click . So for a trial i tried to make an alert box so that i can check if function call works. Ivh-Treeviewe has only checkbox functions. So tried to Add a Custom Template

```
nodeTpl: [
            '<div>',
            '<span ivh-treeview-toggle>',
            '<span ivh-treeview-twistie></span>',
            '</span>',
            '<span href="#here" class="ivh-treeview-node-label" ng-click="test()">',
            '{{trvw.label(node)}}',
            '</span>',
            '<div ivh-treeview-children></div>',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n')
```

and on controller

```
this.test = function() {
alert("hello");
```

}

Bt now the click event isnt invoked. Can some one please resolve this . Also tried to do with $scope.test definition bt it didnt worked.

Comment: Added the script on http://jsbin.com/ropuyeg/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in the fact that ivh-treeview (v1) does not make the your transcluded scope available to your node templates. Essentially, this means things defined in scopes outside your tree will not be accessible by the template. All is not lost though! You have a couple options:

1. Wrap your *on click* logic up in a tidy directive. For example:

   ```
   ...
   '<span href="#here" class="ivh-treeview-node-label" do-fancy-things-on-click>',
   ...
   ```

Here, `do-fancy-things-on-click` is a directive you've defined which listens for a click event, then inspects the `node` on `$scope` and takes some action. You might update the display of the attached element, broadcast an event, interact with a service, etc.

2. Use the v2 branch of ivh-treeview. This is not fully released yet but providing the transcluded scope to your templates is a feature we intend to continue supporting moving forward. I recommend using a [transcluded inline template](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/v2/docs/templates-and-skins.md#inline-templates).

Just note that the reason v2 hasn't fully dropped yet is because we're not done making breaking changes :). I wouldn't expect anything too crazy but if the first option works for you it will certainly continue to work.